# URL for custom functions in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Must I have an URL to implement my custom functions?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
exclude-result-prefixes="#all" 
xmlns:portal="http://www.enonic.com/cms/xslt/portal" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:karusell="" >
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"  />
```

xmlns:karusell=""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your custom functions into a namespace and for that you need to bind a prefix to a URI, yes. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#stylesheet-functions which says "A stylesheet function must have a prefixed name, to remove any risk of a clash with a function in the default function namespace. It is a static error if the name has no prefix".

Comment: I have a prefix but the URI. How to come up width that?

Comment: Usually you would use a URL on a domain you own or your company owns e.g `http://example.com/mf`. But as long as you don't exchange your code with others you can be inventive and use e.g. `http://localhost/mf` or `urn:mf`.